# How to detect when all divs inside of another div are invisible

Tags: jquery

I've my HTML as

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="item">String</div>
    <div class="item">String</div>
    <div class="item">String</div>
</div>
```

Clicking on each `.item` div sets the div clicked to `display: none`. When there are no divs displayed, I want the `#main` div to be set to `display :none` too.

So how do I detect that all the div `.items` inside the `#main` div are in 'display: none` mode using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `:visible` selector:

```
if (! $('#main > div:visible').length) {
    $('#main').hide();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working but the condition check `if (! $('#main > div:visible').length)` doesn't work. But when I changed it to `if ($('#main > div:visible').length==1)` it works as when I click the last `.item`, I want the `#main` div to disappear. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

```
if(!$('.item').is(':visible'))
    $('#main').hide();
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mwGeT/